# How do I use Amazon s3 to host audio files linked from my website?

Tags: amazon-s3, files, data-storage

I wanna make a website to allow users to download audio files . Where can i store those audio file. I read about amazon s3 . What is it and how to use it to store my files ? How to serve those files to the website ? Should the website be hosted on amazon too ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have your website hosted on Amazon.

You can use S3 to store your audio files and then use the public links such as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/audiofilename` inside your website to point to those static files.

Check [how to upload files to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/upload-objects.html) (official guide) and [how to generate public links](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).